# Java Calendar - Set Custom date and time

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to set custom date and time for Calendar object in java. I have to create a date which is 1 day more than current date, and time should be set as "X" (some time like 05:00:00).

Here is what i did till now:

```
Calendar tomorrow = Calendar.getInstance();
tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

wake_up_time = "05:00:00";

Date date_wake_up_time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(wake_up_time);
Calendar cal_wake_up_time = Calendar.getInstance();
cal_wake_up_time.setTime(date_wake_up_time);

tomorrow.set(Calendar.HOUR, cal_wake_up_time.get(Calendar.HOUR));
tomorrow.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cal_wake_up_time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
tomorrow.set(Calendar.SECOND, cal_wake_up_time.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Now when i do `tomorrow.getTimeInMillis()` i should be getting a constant long value, since for a particular day, i am setting the time as constant. But, when i run this code, the long value keeps on changing.

```
Tomorrow Date: 3
Tomorrow Hour: 5
Tomorrow Minute: 0
Tomorrow Second: 0
Tomorrow's Time: 1467522000711

Tomorrow Date: 3
Tomorrow Hour: 5
Tomorrow Minute: 0
Tomorrow Second: 0
Tomorrow's Time: 1467522000169
```

and more over, why is the time value decreasing with each iteration? What am i doing wrong here? How do i set a Calendar to tomorrow's X time?

Comment: Similar: [*Why can't I set an hour and a minute for Java Calendar?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56315817/642706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question is working just fine. The problem was, i didn't set Milliseconds to 0 or a constant (tomorrow.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);) The change was only milliseconds, which i overlooked. This also gave me the assumption that the long value was decreasing each time i executed the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing:

```
Calendar cal_wake_up_time = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Then each time the calendar will have a different time stored so you will have different milliseconds value for it.

If so then you need to clear the values that you are not setting using, either by doing a `clear()` in the beginning or doing it per field using `clear(int field)` (e.g. `clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND)`):

```
tomorrow.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Comment: oh.. ok.. but when i am using, cal_wake_up_time.setTime(date_wake_up_time); will it not override the default time?

Comment: @VamsiChalla But in case of tomorrow you don't setTime, you just add a day to it.

Comment: I also wanted to add some X time for tomorrow's date.

Comment: @VamsiChalla In the above code you don't do it, you just increase the date, and set hour, minute and seconds. Which leaves out milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

You are using outmoded classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Time zone

Time zone is crucial in determine a date. The JVM‘s current default can change at any moment. So always specify the desired/expected time zone explicitly.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

The `Local…` classes have no time zone. These can be used as building blocks to assemble our desired value of “tomorrow” and “at 5 AM”.

A new `LocalTime` object defaults to all zeros. So no need to clear minutes, seconds, and fractional second. And so no problem like that which tripped you up with `Calendar`.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = now.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 );
LocalTime fiveAm = LocalTime.of( 5 , 0 );
ZonedDateTime tomorrowAt0500 = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , fiveAm , zoneId );
```

### Convert

If you must have a `java.util.Calendar` object for use in old code, convert from the java.time type. Look for new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.GregorianCalendar.from( tomorrowAt0500 );
```